# Dynamically loop over a javascript Array where keys are unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An array is in my app(It's a code editor) as follows:

```
var ar =[
         {
           keyword:[
                    {
                     values:['if','else','endif'],
                     style:'vcm-keyword'
                    }
                   ]
         },
         {
           operator:[
                     {
                      values:['==','!=','<','>' ],
                      style:'vcm-operator'
                     }
                    ]
         }
       ];
```

This array is passed to a jQuery plug-in.
Now I want to loop over the array and get the values.
The interesting thing here is the array comes dynamically. Meaning, I don't know what type of keys[in the above array `keyword` and `operator`] will be in array.

Our editor is being developed to support all types of programming languages. So I may not able to know what type of keys will be in that above array.
So, how to loop over an array if its key names are unknown.

Literally this is what I want to do in the plug-in:

```
var values = arr[0].[+key+].values,
    style = arr[0].[+key+].style;
```

**Notes**:I dont know that whether my assumption is right or wrong.Any suggestions/ alternatives are appreciated.

Comment: `for (var key in arr) console.log(values[key]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$(ar).each(function() {

});
```

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: That's not how you use the `jQuery.each()` function, should be: `$.each(ar, function() {...});`. You're confusing that with the `.each()` jQuery function, which is for iterating over a set of matched elements in a jQuery object.

Comment: Anthony that was just for reference, that is why i have attached a link though..sorry for any offences..

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `for..in` construct to loop keys in an object (or array), for example:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

You might also want to throw in a call to [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for good measure, such as:

```
for(var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

That stops you from iterating down the prototype chain etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a

```
foreach
```

statement?